# How would I create multiple arrays using a class constructor without creating more than one array in the class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am working on an exercise in operator overloading. I've created a matrix class and I am supposed to overload operators so I can do arithmetic on matrices efficiently.

My directions say that I am supposed to make two matrix arrays using the class constructor that has 2 parameters and a third matrix array that will be used to store the result of arithmetic using the default constructor (1 parameter).

Since I am going to use these arrays to overload operators they are going to need to be data members of the class (I think). However, I thought that classes were supposed to be as representative of real life things as possible so making a matrix class with multiple arrays doesn't make sense to me (a matrix is only one matrix).

Am I misunderstanding classes or is there a different way to make additional matrices using the class constructor I am not thinking of? Thanks all, here is the code in question.

```
class matrix
{
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const matrix&); // << overloader 

    private:
    int size // size indicates length of rows and cols, so size 3 means a 3 x 3 matrix
    int array[10][10];

    public:
    matrix(int);
    matrix(int, int);
};

matrix:: matrix (int sizeIn) //default constructor, use to make result matrix
{
    int MAX_SIZE = 10;

    if (0 > sizeIn && sizeIn > 10)
    {
     size = MAX_SIZE;
    }
    else
    {
     size = sizeIn;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
             array[i][j] = 0;
}

matrix:: matrix (int sizeIn, int rangeIn) //use to make first 2 matrices that will be added
{
    int range;
    int MAX_SIZE = 10;
    int MAX_RANGE = 20;

    if (0 > sizeIn && sizeIn > 10)
    {
     size = MAX_SIZE;
    }
    else
    {
     size = sizeIn;
    }

    if (0 > rangeIn && rangeIn > 20)
    {
      range = MAX_RANGE;
    }
    else
    {
     range = rangeIn;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            array[i][j] = (rand() % (2 * range + 1) - range); //random number for each index
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const matrix & arrayPrint) // << overloader
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayPrint.size; i++)
    {
        cout << '|';
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayPrint.size; j++)
            {
            os << setw(4) << arrayPrint.array[i][j] << " ";
            }
        os << setw(2) << '|' << endl;
    }
return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the question. You are required to make a Matrix class that has 1 two dimensional array and then use the constructor to make two different matrices and then add them and store the result into a third one. So you will end up with something like this

```
    matrix::matrix(int Size, int Range)
    {
         if(Range < 0 || Range > RANGE_MAX)
             Range = RANGE_MAX;

         if(Size < 0 || Size > SIZE_MAX)
             Size = SIZE_MAX;

        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
               array[i][j] = (rand() % (2 * Range + 1) - Range);
    }
```

Then you will make two matrices A and B as follows

```
matrix A(4,10); // Create a Matrix A size 4 with random entries in range of 10
matrix B(3,8); // Create a Matrix B with size 3 with random entries in range of 8
```

You will then overload the = operator and + operator to let you do the following (of course you need to check if the sizes allow the operation first)

```
matrix C = A + B
```

To overload the "=" operator

```
matrix& matrix::operator=(const matrix &rhs)
{
   // if we have A = B then A is me and B is the rhs
   // assuming all members are public you might need to write get/set functions
   size = rhs.size;         // my size equals the right hand side's size
   range = rhs.range;
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        array[i][j] = rhs.array[i][j];

    return *this;   // return me
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am only supposed to pass the constructor the size and range parameters though, not array.

Comment: @Matt by range you mean column count right? This is quite weird. Are you 100% sure that you cant overload the constructor for the purpose of this assigment. It honestly doesn't make sense at all, unless you want to fill in the matrix after initialization.

Comment: No, range is in reference to the index content so if range = 10, only numbers 1 throught 10 can be generated to be in the array. size determines the row and columns, so a size of 3 would mean a 3 x 3 array.

Comment: @Matt ok I think I got it now. You need to create a Matrix with one 2 dimensional array and then overload the operators. I will edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: I understand how to make the array, if you take a look at the constructor in my code you'll see its pretty much the same as what you edited your example to be. What I don't get is how I am supposed to make two without making additional arrays in my class definition. I'm not familiar with making matrices like you are. I've just been using arrays

Comment: @Matt haha! I just noticed that what I wrote in the constructor is exactly what you did :) So yes you were right in the way you wrote the constructor. Matrices A and B each has its own copy of "array" which is randomly generated. That's how you make two different matrices. They are independant.

Comment: matrix A(3,10);
matrix B(3,10);
<-Are those functions from a library or something?

Comment: @matt No. These two statement go in main(). When you create an object of type matrix (the class that you are writing) then the constructor gets called. so 3 is passed as inSize and 10 is passed as inRange.

Comment: Ok, copy the matrix in main. The questions then are: 1. how would the external matrix arrays created in main be able to be set by the matrix array from the class since it is private. 2.the constructor as it is only generates one matix, two are needed. 3.dont operator overloading functions need to use data members from the class?

Comment: @Matt 1) You can't. The way your instructor wants it won't allow you to do that unless you create a third constructor like the one I wrote in the first version of my answer or you can write a setArray function. 2) Yes that is true! but you are calling it twice once for A and once for B so you end up with 2 matrices. 3) No they don't you can pass them external objects the same way you do with regular functions. You will actually have to do that when implementing the "+" "-" and "=" operators. The "<<" was a special case.

Comment: Thanks for the help and patience! I am not clear on how the outside matrices will receive the array from the constructor. matrixA/B(size, range) are functions and will call the contructors?

Comment: @Matt I added the = operator overload for you. Imagine declaring an integer in C++. You would do this: int i = 0. Right? "int" is the type, "i" is the variable name, and "0" is your initial value. In classes you pass the initial values differently since they are complex types if you want to call them that. Matrix A(3, 10) means: "Matrix" is the type, "A" is the variable name, and (3, 10) are arguements passed to the constructor of class matrix to initialized it accordingly.

Comment: @Matt by the way if you look to the right hand side of the screen stack overflow has many questions similar to yours even some including matrices. Good luck!